# Setting Multiple state using common function in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-hooks, react-functional-component

How to write a common function `handleInputChange` that will take two or more arguments and update the states in the same way.

```
function X(param1 , param2 ,...){}
```

resultant state:

```
 name: {value: param1 , error: param2}
```

Initial state declaration :

```
this.state = {
      name: { value: "", error: "" },
      city: { value: "", error: "" },
      email: { value: "", error: "" },
      contact_number: { value: "", error: "" },
      otp_data: {}
    };
```

My handleInputChange function:

```
handleInputChange = (name, value) => {
    let label = "";
    this.setState({
      [label]: {
        ...this.state[label],
        value: value,
        error: validateFields(label, value)
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some code in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

When using react hooks to manage state of the components it is more common to separate properties if they do not affect each other like this:

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState(`default name, can be left empty`)
const [city, setCity] = React.useState(`default city, can be left empty`)
```

Now you can access state by accessing `name` and `city` and change them by using `setCity('New York`)`.

If you need for whatever reason to group stage like it is done in Class based components you would do it like this:

```
const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({name: 'Milorad', city: 'Svrljig'})
```

Now to change only name you have to `setObj(prev => ({...prev, name: 'Ilija'}))` or in your case where you have key value pairs:

```
const handleInputChange = (key, value) => {
    setObj(prev => ({...prev,
      [key]: {
        ...prev[key],
        value: value,
        error: validateFields(key, value)
      })
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always recommended to create separate state for each variable. In functional component you can use useState as below

```js
const [name, setName] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });
const [city, setCity] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });
const [email, setEmail] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });
const [contact_number, setContactNumber] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });
const [otp_data, setOtpData] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });

// Mapping of label with state changer
const labelStateMap = {
        name: setName,
        city: setCity,
        email: setEmail,
        contact_number: setContactNumber,
        otp_data: setOtpData
}

handleInputChange = (label, value) => {
    const stateChanger = labelStateMap[label];
    if(stateChanger){
        stateChanger({
            value,
            error: validateFields(label, value)
        })
    }
  };
```

Comment: It is always recommended to create separate state for each variable ?

Comment: As you can see, we have used multiple useState for each variable. This can be done by using single useState with whole object contains all variable. But it is not recommended and unable to track when the variable is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own logic, you could consider using [Formik](https://formik.org/) which makes it a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `useState` hook you can do something like this

Make a state variable and initialize it to the initial form data

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  name: { value: "", error: "" },
  city: { value: "", error: "" },
  email: { value: "", error: "" },
  contact_number: { value: "", error: "" },
  otp_data: {},
});
```

And to handle change,

```js
handleInputChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [label]: {
      value,
      error: validateFields(label, value),
    },
  });
};
```

The input to `handleChange` function calls the `setFormData` function returned by the hook and overrides the form data for the changed input.