# How to use useState to store multiple key objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a candlestick chart for a crypto and it has different timeframe for 1 minute, 30, minute, and so on. I currently have

```
const [data, setData] = useState[]
  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPrice = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/apii?slug=${poolName[0].pool_id}&timeframe=`${1h}``); // default is 1h

      const btcusd = data.data.results.map(
        (d) => {
          return {
            open: d.open,
            close: d.close,
            low: d.low,
            high: d.high,
            time: toDateStamp(d.datetime),
          };
        }
      );
      setData(btcusd)
    };

    fetchPrice()
  }, []);
```

The above is the initial state whenever a user visits which he or she will be shown a 1-hour chart data. So there is this onClick button which will fetch and set new state according to he chosen timeframe. It works if i setData for one timeframe but then if I set another timeframe, how do I separate them?

Edit:

My bad guys, I have no issues to have the useffect runs again as i have another useeffect for that purpose whenever a user clicks on a new timeframe. My question is how can I store the chosen timeframes into a state and then re-use them again should the user chooses the timeframe that he chose before? This would be nice as I can stop outgoing network request.

Comment: Please create a state variable to store the array-index for `poolName` and set it to 0 or 1 or other values within the `onClick` method. Let's say you use: `const [chosenIdx, setChosenIdx] = useState(0);` (& within the `onClick` you use `setChosenIdx(1)` based on user-choice 1 or 2 or 0 or other-values), then in the `useEffect` change the `[]` parameter to `[chosenIdx]`.

Comment: hey @thenotorious ! checkout this answer  it will definitely help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066911/setting-multiple-state-using-common-function-in-react-hooks

Comment: @jsN00b7 will the previous timeframe be stored too? Would be nice so then i can stop get request whenever a users chooses the state again.

Answer (score 0):

can use the spread operator inside `setData()` to get the old values, then add the new value, something like this:

```
setData( oldValues => [ ...oldValues, newValue ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set data as object with keys as timeframes f.e.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

const TIMEFRAMES = {
  HOUR: '1h',
  HALF_HOUR: '30min',
};

const hourlyNewData = { price: 1 };

setData((prevdata) => {
  ...prevData,
  [TIMEFRAMES.HOUR]: newData,
});

const minutelyNewData = { price: 1.1 };

setData((prevData) => {
  ...prevData,
  [TIMEFRAMES.HALF_HOUR]: minutelyNewData,
});

// and to access data:
const hourlyData = data[TIMEFRAMES.HOUR];
const minutelyData = data[TIMEFRAMES.HALF_HOUR]
```

Comment: Will the previous timeframe be stored? This would be nice so thhat users don’t have to refetch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your dynamic values, like `1h` and `poolName` to the dependency array like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [1h, poolNames])
```